# mysql multiple conditions with not equal

Tags: mysql

I want something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM chat 
WHERE (user1= :user OR user2= :user) 
AND (deleted1 != :user OR deleted2 != :user) 
ORDER BY year, month, day, time DESC 
LIMIT 20
```

I have this code:

```
SELECT * FROM chat 
WHERE user1= :user OR user2= :user 
AND deleted1 <> :user OR deleted2<> :user 
ORDER BY year, month, day, time DESC 
LIMIT 20
```

I want to first check if is `:user` in `user1` or `user2` and after that to check if `:user` not in `deleted1` or `deleted2`. In many cases `deleted1` and `deleted2` are both empty. But this code what I have it not working like I want.

[image]

This is my table and i want to display all rows where not user1 or user2 in deleted1 or deleted2

Comment: how do you want it to work? can you post some data?

Answer (score 2):

You can try with the following query

```
SELECT *   FROM chat
WHERE      (user1= :user OR user2= :user)
AND        ( deleted1 <> :user )
AND        ( deleted2<> :user)
ORDER BY year, month, day, time DESC
LIMIT 20
```